# Give further examples of morphological alternation patterns such as Verb/Noun (处 chu3 / chu4) and Active/Inactive Verb (好 hao4 / hao3)

Tags: tones, sentence-structure

In [this answer](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/9116/why-is-the-%E4%BC%9A-in-%E4%BC%9A%E8%AE%A1-pronounced-ku%C3%A0i), a few examples of morphological alternation patterns are provided, like Verb/Noun (e.g. 处 chu3 "to dwell" / chu4 "a place") and Active/Inactive Verb (e.g. 好 hao4 "to like" / hao3 "to be good").

Are more complete lists available somewhere? Alternatively, could someone provide more examples? Actually this question has three parts.

1) Are there more characters which are Verb or Noun depending on the pronunciation?

2) Are there more characters which Active/Inactive Verb depending on the pronunciation?

3) Are there other sorts of morphological alternation patterns?

With as many examples as possible. :)

This is a question about modern standard Chinese/普通话.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- 好(hǎo hào)
- 正(chēng zhèng)
- 应(yīng yìng)
- 奔(bēn bèn)
- 卷(juǎn juàn)
- 调(tiáo diào)
- 转(zhuǎn zhuàn)
- 兴(xīng xìng)
- 模(mó mú)
- 系(xì jì)
- 挨(āi ái)
- 挑(tiāo tiǎo)
- 盛(chéng shèng)
- 冠(guān guàn)
- 壳(ké qiào)
- 载(zǎi zài)
- 散(sǎn sàn)
- 强(qiáng qiǎng)
- 供(gōng gòng)
- 薄(báo bó)
- 尽(jǐn jìn)
- 难(nán nàn)
- 种(zhǒng zhòng)
- 更(gēng gèng)
- 处(chǔ chù)
- 乐(lè yuè)

Comment: The question is about morphological alterations, not about characters with several pronunciations. I don't think there's any morphological relation between words such as 樂 lè and 樂 yuè. They are simply homographs.